# Manifest permission section stopped the project

Tags: android

I had vital problem when I am working on my new Android App as when I testing it the traditional message " the project stopped ..."  although when I was testing the app on emulator it worked well , I checked my code and I reached to problem place and it was on manifest on these lines of code :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
     <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />-->
```

but I didn't solve this issue .

Comment: post the logcat that contains the error and stacktrace

Comment: No error appeared to me when testing on emulator but the error appeared when I checked the project on mobile device

Comment: Yes, you can get the logcat from the device using DDMS or `adb logcat` and you will see the error and the cause of it.